# On the equivalence of well-orderering and mathematical induction principles

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

It is a familiar fact that the principle of mathematical induction and the principle of well-ordering are equivalent (in the set of natural numbers). However, the defining property of the natural numbers is the mathematical induction itself, i.e., the set of natural numbers is defined to be the smallest inductive set containing $1$ considering the usual axioms of set theory.

In what sense is the well-ordering principle equivalent to the mathematical induction? Or similarly, how can we define the natural numbers using the usual axioms of set theory minus the axiom of infinity (that there exist inductive sets) plus the principle of well-ordering?

Comment: If you take a reasonable collection of axioms about $\mathbb{N}$ which do not include either the well-ordering principle or induction, then you can prove that the two are logically equivalent. You can also define $\mathbb{N}$ to be the smallest nonempty ordinal where every element has a successor - this is the sort of definition which gives you the well-ordering principle for free and makes you work just a bit for induction.

Comment: @MarkSaving I got it, thanks